# why my timer component is not working as a timer its time is not reducing

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

i have a timer which shows the timer based on the time left by comparing it from now to the time received from server and shows timer what i have done is below, received time is the string like "2020-09-02T05:09:56.119Z" now i want the time to be the difference between time received from server and the time now but my timer is showing two times only as shown in the below gif
[Link to the problem timer](https://share.getcloudapp.com/Qwu0wbbX)

```
 import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
    import {Box, Message, Video, Timer, BlueScreen, Emoji, Heading, SubHeading, WaitingImage} from './styled' ;
    import Button from 'Components/Button';
    import { getAPatient } from '../api';
    import moment from 'moment';
    
    export default function WaitingRoom(){
    
        const { t } = useTranslation();
        const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState();
    
        const url = window.location.href.split('?id=');
        const id = url[1];
    
        const geTimerTime = async () => {
            await getAPatient(id)
            .then((info) => {
                const datetime = info && info.data.datetime;
                const currentTime = moment().toISOString()
                const d1 = new Date(currentTime);
                const d2 = new Date(datetime);
                const difference = d1 - d2;
                if (difference > 60e3){
                   const minutes = Math.floor(difference / 60e3);
                   const seconds = minutes * 60;
                   setTimeLeft(seconds)
                } 
                else {
                   const seconds =  Math.floor(difference / 1e3);
                   setTimeLeft(seconds)
                }
                console.log(currentTime, datetime,difference,"infopoooo")
            })
            .catch((err) => {
               console.log(err)
            });
        }
    
        useEffect(() => {
             geTimerTime()
          
            if (!timeLeft) return;
      }, [timeLeft]);
    
        return(
         timeLeft === 0 ?
        <BlueScreen>
            <Emoji>
                <Smiley />
            </Emoji>
            <Heading>
                {t('turnMessageHeading')}
            </Heading>
            <SubHeading>
                {t('turnMessageSubHeading')}
            </SubHeading>
            <SubHeading>
            {t('turnMessageSubHeadingDoctor')}
            </SubHeading>
            <Button
              themeWhite  
            >
                {t('commingMessage')}
            </Button>
         </BlueScreen>
         :
           <Box>
               <Button 
                themeBlue
                width={'100%'}
                textAlign={'left'}
               >
                {t('Virtual_waiting_room')}    
               </Button>
               <Message>
                    {t('waiting_message')}
               </Message>
               <Timer>
                    <div>{Math.floor(timeLeft/60) + ':' + ('0' + Math.floor(timeLeft % 60)).slice(-2)}</div> minutes
               </Timer>
               <WaitingImage>
                <Waiting />
               </WaitingImage>
               <Video>
                <iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/gaka1vqYFNs'
                    frameborder='0'
                    allow='autoplay; encrypted-media'
                    allowfullscreen
                    title='video'
                    width={"100%"}
                />
               </Video>
    
           </Box> 
        )
    }
```

Comment: because you call `setTimeLeft`, and that triggers a rendering.

Comment: @MarioVernari ohh thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is simply because you call `setTimeLeft`, which sets the state for `timeLeft`, which in react **triggers a re-render**, during which all the `useEffect()` hooks will run, except for those that are not listening to changes on a state variable.

Furthermore, you have `timeLeft` in the dependency array (the second parameter in the hook), which means this `useEffect()` will run on every re-render where `timeLeft` state was set, thus running on each iteration.

If you need your `useEffect()` to run like `componentDidMount`, you need to keep an empty dependency array, thus ensuring the hook only runs on initial render

```
useEffect(() => {
         geTimerTime()
      
        if (!timeLeft) return;
  }, []);//empty dependency array to mimic componentDidMount
```

Comment: can you please tell me why the timer is not working it is just showing me two times and not the timer here is what happening https://share.getcloudapp.com/Qwu0wbbX

Comment: still after empty array it is rerendering

Answer (score 0):

**useEffect's** set state Function should not match the second parameter. The useEffects is run whenever any data inside the second parameter's array is changed. Since you are changing the timeLeft inside the useEffects it will run infinitely. If you want to do geTimerTime anyway and have the timeLeft inside the dependency array(second parameter to useEffect) then you can do like below

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (timeLeft) {
        geTimerTime();
    }
}, [timeLeft])
```